# Mark specific table row

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table- similar to the one below:

[image]

This is how I create my table:

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");

            while (0 < table.rows.length) {
                table.deleteRow(0);
            }

            for (var i = dataRaw.length; i > 0; i--) {
                var r = dataRaw[i - 1];
                var row = table.insertRow(0);
                row.id = r[0];
                for (var x = 0; x < r.length; x++) {

                    if (i === 1) {
                        var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
                        headerCell.innerHTML = r[x];
                        row.appendChild(headerCell);
                    } else {
                        var cell = row.insertCell(x);
                        cell.innerHTML = r[x];
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to highlight product ID = 2 with fx. At red dot or icon outside of the table:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can do what you're asking several ways.  You could get the X/Y co-ordinates of the cell and add an absolute positioned element, or you could add an extra column at the beginning of each row that has no visible attributes (border etc.), except for that 1 row.  However, it would be a lot easier to just add it inside the cell.

Comment: how do you decide which row to put the dot/icon? is it always row 2?

Comment: No not always same row. I have i list...

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the `::before` selector:

```js
const dataRaw = [
  ['ID', 'Name', 'Quality'],
  [0, 'Foo', '25%'],
  [1, 'Bar', '50%'],
  [2, 'Baz', '75%']
];
const table = document.getElementById("table");
const activeID = 2;

while (0 < table.rows.length) {
    table.deleteRow(0);
}

for (var i = dataRaw.length; i > 0; i--) {
    var r = dataRaw[i - 1];
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    row.id = r[0];
    for (var x = 0; x < r.length; x++) {
        if (i === 1) {
            var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = r[x];
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
        } else {
            var cell = row.insertCell(x);
            if (i - 1 === activeID) {
              cell.className += 'active';
            }
            cell.innerHTML = r[x];
        }
    }
}
```

```css
table {
  margin: 15px;
}

td.active::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  content: '•';
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
</table>
```

Comment: this is static, i think he need it in dynamically.

Comment: I mentioned that in the last sentence. He could dynamically add the “active” class wherever needed when building the table.

Comment: This will only add content though, not an element that can be styled.  I doubt you can achieve what the OP has shown in the question this way.

Comment: The question says "red dot or icon". Can't you handle that with CSS `content`?